# Written text file in C is empty and does not show any characters

Tags: c, codeblocks

This program should start by reading any keyboard input, then writing one character a time to a disk file, called test.ext

To terminate the code you should be able to input the EOF sequence (Crt^z for Windows I believe).

Input - keyboard
 Output - test.txt (disk file)

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
    FILE *ptr;
    char ch;

    ptr = fopen("test.txt", "w");

    do {
        ch = getchar();
        putchar(ch);
    } while (ch != EOF);

    fclose(ptr);
}
```

Comment: `putchar(ch)` writes to stdout, so the file stays empty.

Comment: `ptr` is not being used - that should give you a hint..

Comment: It needs to be `int ch`, otherwise `ch != EOF` will probably not work.

Comment: Also, when you get EOF you need to break out of the loop *before* you write the character to the file. Use `while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`putchar()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/putchar/) which:

> Writes a character to the standard output (stdout).

When you really want to be writing to your `ptr` file. You can write to files with [`fprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/) like this:

```
fprintf(ptr, "%c", ch);
```

Or even better you can use [`fputc()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fgetc-fputc-c/) to write a single character to a file:

```
fputc(ch, ptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a function like `fputc()` that has an extra parameter for the output stream to which you can chose where the output should be directed, as opposed to `putchar()` which writes to `stdout` only:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *ptr;
    char ch;

    ptr = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    if (!ptr)
    {
        perror("test.txt");
        return 1;
    }

    do {
        ch = getchar();
        fputc(ch, ptr); //note this line
    } while (ch != EOF);


    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very very much, this helped a lot.  I did replace         "putchar(ch)" with  "fputc(ch, ptr)"  and got my text display in the file, but oddly enough this character kept showing up at the very end of each file " ÿ ". Any particular reason for this?